# Is it possible to make a WebSocket connection in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, websocket

Is it possible to make a WebSocket connection in Silverlight? Or if not, does anyone know whether this is scheduled for future versions?

Answer (score 3):

Ostensibly yes.

In fact it has been used to provide a fall back solution for browsers that don't support WebSockets.

See the following for more info but note that this implementation is against v75 not v76 (latest).

Demo: http://40interop.ep.interop.msftlabs.com/html5/wschat.html

Info:
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/07/27/silverlight-and-websockets.aspx

Info: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2010/07/silverlight-html5-websocket-client-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Some vendors provide WebSocket APIs for client environments other than JavaScript. [Kaazing](https://kaazing.com/), for example, has full-fledged support for .NET/Silverlight clients (in addition to Flash/Flex, and Java.

> *Note:* Kaazing now provides AngularJS, ReactJS, Objective-C (iOS), Xamarin (.NET with support for iOS and Android), [Java](http://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/jms_client_docs/dev-java/o_dev_java.html), [.NET](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/websocket_client_docs/dev-dotnet/o_dev_dotnet.html), and Android clients. However support for SilverLight and Flash have been deprecated.

Here you find [complete documentation](https://kaazing.com/documentation/), and you may want to check out some of the fancy demos [here](https://kaazing.com/demos/) too.