# Calling a WebSocket from Silverlight client example code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, html, websocket

The WebSockets samples on the HTML5 Labs site ([here](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5labs/prototypes/websockets/websockets/documentation)) do not include a Silverlight example. Perhaps I missed it somewhere?

I’ve tried various calls to make a socket connection but nothing is working. The ready state is staying at “connecting.”

Here’s some code. I have a listener waiting on port 4502 at the same uri as shown below.

```
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + uriString);
        ws.OnOpen += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(ws_OnOpen);
        ws.Open();


    void ws_OnOpen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ws.SendMessage(myMessage);
    }
```

Looking at Fiddler, I don’t see any calls being made.

Has anyone tried the prototype code from a SL client?

Comment: I would highlight recommend you review the options in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819621/is-it-possible-to-make-a-websocket-connection-in-silverlight

Comment: That's the code I have been working with. So far it works from jQuery as shown in the demo but not from Silverlight.

Comment: Did you deploy the client access policy file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the WebSocket object was falling out of scope and thus being disposed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a Javascript wrap of Silverlight WebSocket.

You also can take a look at WebSocket4Net, which is a C# websocket which has a Silverlight implementation.